# Segmentation Fault When Trying to Change Values at Memory Address

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc

I have spotted down an error of seg fault, which occurred to be in my divideBlock() function. When I dereferenced newBlock to access info, i.e. without assigning value to it but just dereferencing it, it was alright, but when I change its value, I received a set fault. Any idea why this would happen? Could it be because of the address manipulation and non-standard pointer access? If so, what should I do if I want to break one block into two?

```
typedef struct freeBlock
{
    size_t info;
    struct freeBlock *next;
} freeBlock;

freeBlock *divideBlock(freeBlock *block, size_t reqSize)
{
    // Declaration of variables.
    freeBlock *newBlock;
    size_t blockSize;

    blockSize = block->info >> 1;
    newBlock = block + reqSize;

    newBlock->info = (blockSize - reqSize) << 1; // new block marked as unused. seg fault happens here!!!
    block->info = (reqSize << 1) | 1; // old block marked as used.

    return newBlock;
}

void *malloc(size_t size)
{
    if (size == 0)
        return NULL;
    // Declaration of variables. 
    size_t blockSize, occpd, poccpd, reqSize;
    freeBlock *curr, *prev, *newBlock, *allocd, *combined;

    printf("%d", __LINE__);
    reqSize = (size + sizeof(size_t) + sizeof(char*) + padding + (align - 1)) & ~ (align - 1);

    printf("%d", __LINE__);
    curr = head;
    prev = NULL;
    while (curr != NULL)
    {
    printf("%d", __LINE__);
        occpd = curr->info & 1;

        if (prev != NULL)
        {
    printf("%d", __LINE__);
            poccpd = prev->info & 1;
            if (!poccpd && !occpd)
            {
                 combined = combineBlock(prev, curr);
                if (combined)
                    curr = combined;
            }
        }

        blockSize  = curr->info >> 1;

    printf("%d", __LINE__);
        if (blockSize >= reqSize && !occpd)
        {
            if (blockSize >= 2 * reqSize)
            {
                newBlock = divideBlock(curr, reqSize);
                if (newBlock != NULL)
                {
                    newBlock->next = curr->next;
                    curr->next = newBlock;
                }
            }
            curr->info |= 1;
            return curr + sizeof(char*) + sizeof(size_t);
        }
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    printf("%d", __LINE__);

    allocd = sbrk(reqSize * 3);
    if (allocd == (void*)-1)
        return NULL;

    allocd->info = ((reqSize * 3) << 1) | 1;
    newBlock = divideBlock(allocd, reqSize);
    newBlock->next = NULL;
    allocd->next = newBlock;

    if (head == NULL)
        head = allocd;
    else
        curr = allocd;

    return allocd + sizeof(char *) + sizeof(size_t);
}
```

Comment: How do you allocate the memory of `freeBlock *block`?

Comment: I used sbrk(). This is supposed to be part of an implementation of malloc() and it should break one trunk of free memory into two if it is too big of the desired.

Comment: Your question is still not clear to me, but `block + reqSize` might not do what you think it does.

Comment: Looks like _undefined behaviour_ as given. Please read about pointer arithmetic in C. And please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Provide the function argument value details,and show the code snip of memory allocation.

Comment: Let's say block is the pointer pointing to a freeBlock object that has a size of 128. However, the size required, hence reqSize, by the client is only 32. What I want to do is to break of the block into two. The pointer passed in would point at the first block and newBlock the second. The first will have size 32 and be marked as used. The second will have 96, and be marked free. My problem is that I could set values to my second block because whenever I do it I receive a seg fault. However, if I just do newBlock->info; I do not receive the seg fault error but it is not what I want apparently.

Comment: I have added my malloc implementation. It is quite long but hopefully it will clarify things up a bit.

Comment: `a freeBlock object that has a size of 128` -> 128 what? bytes?

Comment: @Wimmel yes. Sorry if I seem nooby but I'm new to this community and to this area of programming as well.

Comment: @Wimmel and doing that addition was supposed to get me a pointer that points at the start of the new block. How could it be done in a better way?

Comment: This line: `newBlock = block + reqSize` does not increase `newBlock` by `reqSize` bytes, but much more. Probably 8 times `newBlock`. Are you aware of that?

Comment: @Wimmel that is not what I wanted. I want the newBlock pointer to point at the address that is after reqSize of block. Not to increase the size of block. I think I would do it when dealing with block->info...

Comment: As Wimmel points out: The code `newBlock = block + reqSize;` looks strange. It is the same as `newBlock = &block[reqSize]` Is that really what you are trying to do? I guess `newBlock` points outside the memory available. What is the purpose of that code?

Comment: @StillLearning but if I allocate through sbrk() 128bytes of memory and make block point to it. Then I add 32 bytes to the address block points to. Why would it be out of range? Shouldn't this give me an address in the memory that I can assign to a pointer?

Comment: @skydiving94 "Then I add 32 bytes" - no, you don't. You add 32 `freeBlock`s.

Comment: Block is a freeBlock pointer. When you add a number N to a pointer, you actually increment the address by N * (size_of_struct_pointed_to).

Comment: @StillLearning really? That makes a lot of sense. Then what do you suggest me do if I want to have another pointer newBlock that points 32bytes after where block is pointing at?

Comment: @melpomene I see. That makes sense why I go out of range haha.

Comment: Well - If you really want to do that you need to cast the pointer to a type which is exactly 1 byte. Code like `addr = ((char*)block) + 1` will increment address by 1 while `addr = block + 1` will increment address by sizeof(freeBlock).

Comment: @StillLearning I realize there are also problems with the way I return the pointers I think. Because it is just not as simple as adding some number after block but to do something else.

Comment: @StillLearning can you be more specific about what you suggest? Like how should I type it in my case?

Comment: @StillLearning actually nvm I got what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe - but first I need to make sure I fully understand what you are trying to do. You want to allocate a block of memory and map a freeBlock struct to the start of that memory and give the remaing part of the block to the user who called malloc. Correct? Besides that you want to be able to split a block into two blocks. Correct?

Comment: @StillLearning I am not sure about mapping but yep I want to allocate a block of memory, which is bigger than required to call fewer sbrk, break it, and then return it to the user. Block->next will point at the new block that is broken off.

Comment: @StillLearning I think my program is working as expected now. Thank you very much! If you want you could post an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be the line:

```
newBlock = block + reqSize;
```

newBlock will point to a location (address) which is "location-of-block + reqSize*sizeof(freeBlock)"

Probably the intention is simply that newBlock shall point to the location reqSize bytes after block.

To increment a pointer by 1 you can cast it to char* before adding reqSize.

Maybe something like this for the divide:

```
freeBlock *divideBlock(freeBlock *block, size_t reqSize)
{
    // Declaration of variables.
    freeBlock *newBlock;
    size_t blockSize;

    blockSize = block->info >> 1;
    newBlock = (freeBlock*)(((char*)block) + reqSize);

    newBlock->info = (blockSize - reqSize) << 1;
    block->info = (reqSize << 1) | 1; // old block marked as used.

    return newBlock;
}
```

but you also have problems in malloc function where you add numbers to pointers of freeBlock type. Probably not what you want.

BTW:
Why do you use

```
sizeof(char *) + sizeof(size_t)
```

Shouldn't that be

```
sizeof(freeBlock)
```

Comment: Yea that was stupid lol. I will have it fixed! And I have also casted the pointers the way you showed me. It works!